# Why does .vimrc not set colorscheme properly?

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme

So I have downloaded `proton.vim` (a colorscheme) and placed it inside my `.vim/colors` folder.

In .vimrc, right at the bottom I have

```
colorscheme proton
```

but when Vim loads, it is set to the default colorscheme. If I type

```
:colorscheme proton
```

after it has loaded, it works fine though. Anyone know what else I need to do to persist this colorscheme?

Comment: I don't know if it will help you, but if `proton` is a colorscheme for the gui version of Vim, you could try creating  a `.gvimrc` file, and write the line `colorscheme proton` at the end of it.

Comment: Or perhaps there already *is* a gvimrc file that overrides this (this file is only loaded when using Gvim). Otherwise you can try following [the steps here](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/51) and/or posting your full vimrc file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this to help troubleshoot the issue:

1. Check the location where you have downloaded the color proton.vim file.

   On Linux, the system default will be something like `/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors/`

   On MSWindows, the system default will be something like   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim74\colors\`

   You could also try setting up a home directory for colors: `$HOME/.vim/colors` on Linux, or `$HOME/vimfiles/colors` on MSWindows.
2. See if the color scheme shows up outside of your `~/.vimrc`

   Restart vim, then per [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331940/how-to-get-the-list-of-all-installed-color-schemes-in-vim), type

   `:colorscheme` then <kbd>Space</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>

   This should list your colorscheme along with all other color schemes.

**Note:**  <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> returns one list which shows all color schemes.

If you use  `:colorscheme` then <kbd>Space</kbd> followed by <kbd>TAB</kbd> you will iterate over the list of color schemes, one at a time, each time you press <kbd>TAB</kbd>

You can also see this behaviour if you use  `:colorscheme` then <kbd>Space</kbd> followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>  ; you will iterate over the list of color schemes, one at a time, each time you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>

When I troubleshoot an issue like this, I prefer <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> so I may see the entire list at once.

3. type

   `:let colors_name`

   to return the name of the current colorscheme in use by vim
4. If you've added it to `~/.vimrc`

   to confirm which .vimrc file is being loaded by vim, type

   `:scriptnames`

   This will show you the path to the `.vimrc`, 
   the path to the current colorscheme loaded,
   and all scripts sourced so far.

   This file will be  `~\_vimrc` on MSWindows.

Comment: You've used control-d (to get the list of colorschemes) where I've always used tab.  Is there a difference?  (:h for control-d just witters on pointlessly about scrolling downwards).

Comment: There's a difference.  :-)   I have expanded the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the color scheme's name is mentioned properly, for case sensitivity.
Also, check whether

```
let colors_name = "name"
```

is found or not. If not, add this line and try again.

Comment: Thanks, this helped for me. It somehow worked inside `screen` without this though.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when the colorscheme name (as in `let g:colors_name = "selenized"` inside colorscheme file) contained uppercase letters. Changing it to lowercase fixed the problem.